# Exclude some parts of regex match output?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have strings:

```
str1 = "(name)"
str2 = "name"
```

My faulty regexp:

```
output1 = /^name[[:alpha:]]{1,50}/.match(str1)
output2 = /^name[[:alpha:]]{1,50}/.match(str2)
```

Outputs:

```
output1: nil
output2: #<MatchData "name">
```

I need a regexp which will produce "output2" output for both strings. It should expect multiple or zero non-alpha chars and expect those in the beginning of the string.

Comment: Are you familiar with [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/)? It's very helpful when crafting and debugging regexps.

Comment: "...beginning of the screen"? Do you mean string?

Comment: Sorry for "screen" its now -> "string". 'pdoherty..' its awesome tool thank you. I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is capture the first word at the start of a string:

```
%w[(name) name].each do |s|
  puts s[/^[^a-z]*([a-z]+)/i, 1]
end
# >> name
# >> name
```

which will catch the usual ASCII word characters.

http://rubular.com/r/104ylEQg2l

`s[/^\W*([a-z]+)/i, 1]` is Ruby shorthand to find a substring, or pattern, in a string. See [`String.[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) for more information.

Using the POSIX `[:alpha:]` character set to capture the UNICODE word characters:

```
%w[(name) name].each do |s|
  puts s[/^[^[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]]+)/, 1]
end
# >> name
# >> name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Pro answer

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp does not account for any non-alpha characters at the beginning. Try something like this:

```
^\W*name\W*
```

Comment: Be careful using `\w`. It isn't defined as `[a-zA-Z]`, it's `[A-Za-z0-9_]` which are the values used for most variable names, but not words. As a result your pattern will leak digits and underscores.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not excludes \W from output. (Almost there)